# Pass all arguments from outer function to inner function C

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

How would I go about passing all arguments to an inside function? I cannot find an answer anywhere for C.

Here's the basic idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
void customPrint(arguments) {
  Serial.print(arguments);
  Serial.print(arguments);
}
```

I've tried argc/argv syntax as well as `...` syntax but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Impossible. Only enumerate all arguments manually. Or, you can use a macro like `#define customPrint(...) do { Serial.print(__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)` but it's its own can of worms. Or, if the function you're calling supports `va_args` like `vfprintf`, you can go with `va_args`/`va_begin`/etc

Comment: Also, are you sure it's C, not C++? I believe C does not have have methods like `Serial.print`. Unless emulated with function pointers.

Comment: @yeputons it is C++ and it is arduino for sure

Comment: If it's at least C++11, [variadic templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/ellipses-and-variadic-templates) for functions + (optionally) perfect forwarding are for the rescue.

Comment: If you want C-style variadic arguments, there are plenty of tutorials online. You could easily create such a function taking a `printf`-like format string, use `vsnprintf` to get the needed size, allocate memory for a string big enough, use `vsnprintf` again to actually create the string, and pass the string to `Serial.print`.

Comment: If you want C++ variadic templates, there are plenty of tutorials and examples too, all over the Internet. And this would be a much better choice IMO.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP wants to use methods from this class. He vendors not know that is C++.

Comment: Whoever told you that this is C, lied.

Comment: Variadic macros should be available in C and C++ both, so that's the obvious choice. Best practices however, is to avoid variable arguments - their existence is often a sign of design smell.

Answer (score 2):

You need a function which accepts a `va_list` argument. None of the Arduino print variants accept this type of argument.

So it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> the basic idea of what I'm trying to do

does not fit to your question.

If you want a `customPrint` function, which calls various overloads of the `Stream::print` method, you have to implement those overloaded functions.

```
void customPrint( double val, uint_8t digits=2);
void customPrint( long val, uint_8t base = 10);
```

etc.

BTW: Hiding `Serial` inside that function isn't very smart, IMHO.

The other answer "So it is not possible" is correct as well, regarding your question.